# Is there a translation for "solitary work" without negative connotation (side meaning)?

Tags: english-to-german, synonym

I am translating a text about somebody who did "solitary and theoretical work". I assume "solitary" is here used as opposite to "in a team", so "einsam" or "alleine" would not do. How would you translate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used 'einzelgängerische Arbeit'. It seemed to be the best fit for me.

Thank you all for your input!!!

Comment: *Einzelgängerisch* does have a pretty strong connotation though, typically negative. I would understand it as someone who actively avoids teamwork and defends his/her area of responsibility.

Answer (score 9):

I would either say *eigenständige Arbeit* or *Soloprojekt*, if it's a project.

Answer (score 4):

I'd propose "als Einzelner", assuming this is about a scientist or mathematician doing serious research.

"allein" is also almost neutral and could be used.

"einsam" could be appropriate if his ideas were opposed by the community.

Answer (score 0):

`Einsam` would do it, or `selbständig`.

Comment: "Ich arbeite einsam", that's not very common.

Comment: "in einsamer Heimarbeit entstand ...", oder "im einsamen Elfenbeinturm". Leistungen sind mitunter "einsame Klasse".